# Cron job permission denied

Tags: permissions, cron, sudo, cron-task

I'm running a python script called TGubuntu.py.
I used `ls -l` , and the permissions of the script are `-rwxrwxrwx 1 ubuntu ubuntu   503 Jan 13 19:07 TGubuntu.py`, which should mean that anyone can execute the file, right?

But I still get in the log `/bin/sh: 1: /home/ubuntu/TestTG/TGubuntu.py: Permission denied` for some reason.
 When I run the script manually it works perfectly.
Any Ideas?

I put it in the sudo crontab like this

`* * * * * /home/ubuntu/TestTG/TGubuntu.py`

But even in the root (cron) mail log it says Permission Denied!

Comment: Incomplete question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Couldn't figure out what the problem was, so I accomplished my goal using a different method.
I ran a python script that uses the `schedule` module to call my script. Then I just let the "Timer" run on screen indefinitely.

Comment: Terrible solution.